# Plugin for change company in Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I need to create plugin for Dynamics CRM Online which randomly changes company name after editing the contact's fields.
As I know I need to change parentcustomerid field, but I don't know how to get all customer IDs аnd assign one of them in plugin's code.

My code:

```
public class ContactPlugin: IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
            context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            if (entity.LogicalName == "contact") 
            {
                //entity.Attributes.Add("parentcustomerid", GetNewParentCustomerId());              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, write a function to retrieve all accounts from CRM:

```
static List<Entity> GetAllAccounts(IOrganizationService service)
{
    var query = new QueryExpression { EntityName = "account", ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(false) };
    var accounts = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.ToList();

   return accounts;
}
```

Then store an instance of `Random` class at the top of your plugin class:

```
static Random random  = new Random();
```

Then write a function which can retrieve a random item from a list:

```
static Entity GetRandomItemFromList(List<Entity> list)
{
    var r = random.Next(list.Count);
    return list[r];
}
```

Call the functions to first get all of your accounts and then to select one at random:

```
var accounts = GetAllAccounts(service);
var randomAccount = GetRandomItemFromList(accounts);
```

Then convert the `randomAccount` Entity to an EntityReference and assign the value to your contact's `parentcustomerid` attribute:

```
entity.Attributes.Add("parentcustomerid", new randomAccount.ToEntityReference());
```

To update the contact and insert the value into the database, use `service.Update(entity)`. However, if you plan to call `Update` straight away in your code, I'd suggest reinstantiating your contact so that only the `parentcustomerid` attribute is updated in the database:

```
var updatedContact = new Entity { Id = entity.Id, LogicalName = entity.LogicalName };
updatedContact.Attributes.Add("parentcustomerid", new randomAccount.ToEntityReference());
```

Comment: Thank you for help, i did what i wanted.